# Button submit for a JSONP request returning jquery string along with the requested JSON

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I observed a difference when I changed my input button to input submit for my go button on a page which calls my web service to return a JSON. The JSON returned for the button is correct where as the submit is returning an extra random string  which is giving me a parse error.

here is the JSON I got as a response when I did the submit.

```
**jQuery1640658714344437076_1394552371285**

({"Addresses":[{"AddressDeliveryInstallation":" ","AddressExtras":" ","AddressHouseNumber":"115","AddressKey":"14850471315","AddressLine1":"115 Ithaca Rd","AddressLine2":" ","AddressLockBox":" ","AddressPostDirection":" ","AddressPreDirection":" ","AddressPrivateMailboxName":" ","AddressPrivateMailboxRange":" ","AddressRouteService":" ","AddressStreetName":"Ithaca","AddressStreetSuffix":"Rd","AddressSuiteName":" ","AddressSuiteNumber":" ","AddressTypeCode":"S","AreaCode":"607","CBSACode":"27060","CBSADivisionCode":" ","CBSADivisionLevel":" ","CBSADivisionTitle":" ","CBSALevel":"Metropolitan Statistical Area","CBSATitle":"Ithaca, NY","CarrierRoute":"C029","CensusBlock":"5010","CensusTract":"001300","City":"Ithaca","CityAbbreviation":"Ithaca","CompanyName":" ","CongressionalDistrict":"23","CountryCode":"US","CountryName":"United States of America","CountyFIPS":"36109","CountyName":"Tompkins","DeliveryIndicator":"R","DeliveryPointCheckDigit":"1","DeliveryPointCode":"15","DomainName":" ","EmailAddress":" ","Gender":"M","Gender2":" ","Latitude":"42.438395","Longitude":"-76.480396","MailboxName":" ","NameFirst":"Mark","NameFirst2":" ","NameFull":"Mark Lorentzen","NameLast":"Lorentzen","NameLast2":" ","NameMiddle":" ","NameMiddle2":" ","NamePrefix":" ","NamePrefix2":" ","NameSuffix":" ","NameSuffix2":" ","NewAreaCode":" ","PhoneExtension":" ","PhoneNumber":"6072218953 ","PhonePrefix":"221","PhoneSuffix":"8953","PlaceCode":"3638077","PlaceName":"Ithaca","PostalCode":"14850-4713","RecordExtras":" ","RecordID":"1","Reserved":" ","Results":"AC02,AC03,AS01,DA10,DA30,GS05,NS01,NS05,NS06,PS02,PS07,VR01,VR04","Salutation":"Mr. Lorentzen","State":"NY","StateName":"New York","TopLevelDomain":" ","UTC":"-05:00","UrbanizationName":" "}],"Message":"AC02: State Change;AC03: City Change;AS01: Address matched to postal database;DA10: Name appended;DA30: Phone appended;GS05: Geocoded to rooftop level;PS02: Phone number matched to 7 digit level;PS07: Phone number on a cellular line;VR01: Individual name and address match;VR04: Address and phone match;","Success":true});
```

P.S. I am not posting any code as I know the code isn't causing this. I will post it if you think that can be helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for my problem. Parsed my JSON to ignore the jquery token string.